#  Hide and display the Header on scrolling up and down in a array list in android

Tags: android, arraylist

I am trying to implement the following requirement in android. I have two list adapters. One is displaying the header content and another to display an array list with some data under every header item.
e.g:->
Header1
list item
list item
Header2
list item
list item
list item
Header3 
list item
list item
list item
list item

When you scroll up the Header2 two should merge the Header1 and when you scroll up it should expand the header part in expandable format as the shown above. I have gone through some of the example but I am unable to find any proper solution to this. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public void main (husp);
```